# Looking for original reference/derivation for expansion of $J_0\left(z\sin\alpha\right)$ in terms of squared Bessel functions and cosines

Tags: reference-request, bessel-functions

Several tables list the following equality for the Bessel functions $J_{\nu}\left(x\right)$:

$$J_0\left(z\sin\alpha\right)= J_0\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) + 2\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}J_l^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) \cos\left(2l\alpha\right)$$

Examples:

- Magnus, Wilhelm *et al.* *Formulas and Theorems for the Special Functions of Mathematical Physics.* DOI: 10.1007/978-3-662-11761-3

referenced by

- Gradshteyn, Izrail Solomonovich *et al.* Zwillinger, Daniel; Moll, Victor Hugo (eds.). *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*

I am trying to find the original source of this expression to see how it was derived (I am not looking for a derivation with this question). *Magnus, Wilhelm et al.* listed above is the oldest source I have found so far.

Comment: did you Look on  A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions by G. N. Watson?

Comment: @Bernstein I am currently working throught it, but so far I have not found anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced this expression for $J_0\left(z\sin\alpha\right)$ back to

Carl Neumann. *Theorie der Bessel'schen Functionen: Ein Analogon zur Theorie der Kugelfunktionen*. B. G. Teubner, Leipzig 1867.

as referenced from

G. N. Watson. *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*, Cambridge University Press.

Actually, the former does not contain the actual expression, but it can be easily constructed from the expressions given and it analyzes the convergence of this series.